# Как защитить приложение от удаления?

Tags: android, удаление-программ

Как защитить Android приложение от относительно штатных методов удаления (через настройки, Launcher)? Понятно, что через `su -c pm` можно удалить даже системное приложение, но речи не идёт о защите от таких термоядерных методов. Знаю, что можно пересобрать прошивку: прокинуть apk в `/system/app` и радоваться жизни. Но ради этого пересобирать прошивку - дело такое, плюс речь идёт об уже прошитом устройстве и об уже установленных приложениях, а перепрошивать только ради приложений или переустанавливать приложения желания нету. Есть решения? Неважно, какие: shell-скрипт, Android приложение, макрос/плагин к MacroDroid (не Tasker, пж!).

Comment: Никак, так как это осуществляется над-системой, операционкой, по сути, над которой приложение не имеет контроля.

Comment: эм, есть же блокировщики приложений, коих полно в том же Play Market. Да и, опять же, речи не идёт о защите от root-прав (su -c pm uninstall), а о перекрытии лишь относительно очевидных и штатных методов